# Twitter in Android

Tags: android, twitter

I am creating twitter client for android using twitter 4j,Oauth protocol.when i am connecting to twitter. a web page is opened in browser where we can give username and password with two buttons allow and deny.but in the next time the webpage does not ask username and password rather it asked only allow or deny.why this happened?does the browser keeps my username and password in the cookies?any body who come across this situation give me a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > does the browser keeps my username and password in the cookies?

No, of course no. It only keeps the session. That's why you don't have to enter your user/pass again.

Comment: How to close my session once  i don't want ?

Comment: Try to launch the browser pointing to the logout URL of twitter... something like http://twitter.com/logout

Comment: I am not sure this is exactly what is going on. @ForceClose : do you see the "may app <your app name> access twitter" dialog? And if you click yes, do you get a pin?